# How to use Android Device as Wireless Headphones for TV?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, headphones

I go running in the morning and I'd like to use the Sony Internet TV in the basement without waking up my family. Is there any way to connect my Galaxy Nexus to the TV as a wireless headphone set, so that audio streams from the TV to my phone? My TV model is the Sony HX929.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?