# Stream video to TV, but keep audio on phone/tablet

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, streaming

Does anyone know of an app or method that can be used to stream video to the television, but keep the audio on another device? The new Roku 3 has a headphone jack on the remote, but I figure something similar could be done with a phone/tablet, maybe either Plex, XMBC, etc...

The file source wouldn't need to be the phone/tablet, as it could be streaming from a media server.

It looks like a similar question was asked, but it hasn't received an answer.

[How to use Android Device as Wireless Headphones for TV?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40679/how-to-use-android-device-as-wireless-headphones-for-tv)